# IF statement is not formatted correctly and not sure how to fix

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to set the startDate of the query to fiirst_completed based on a set of 'if true' conditions. I am getting an error that the syntax is wrong.
I am open to suggestions on how to do this.
I am including the entire query that I am working with as well as the piece separately that is giving me trouble.

specific part of query that is throwing an error

```
SELECT 
    IF (coolingHours is null AND rowNum = min(rowNum) THEN ''',startDate,''':= first_completed END IF, 
    rowNum,l.logId,l.completed,l.next_completed,l.first_completed,
    isError,charge,totalTimeRange,startingDate,endingDate,coolingHours,
    databaseName,i.name,l.itemId, kwDifference, cost, costT,l.details,timeInSeconds
  FROM tempTable3 l
   inner join items i ON l.logId = i.logId AND i.name LIKE ''%KW PRE%'' 
   WHERE l.itemId = ''',myItemId,'''
        AND completed BETWEEN ''', startDate, ''' AND ''', endDate, '''
```

Sample Data

row Num completed   next_completed  first_completed cooling Hours
10  11/27/2013 1:05:45 AM   11/29/2013 11:18:34 PM  11/25/2013 11:21:15 PM  (null)
11  11/29/2013 11:18:34 PM  11/30/2013 7:37:45 PM   11/27/2013 1:05:45 AM   20.3197
12  11/30/2013 7:37:45 PM   11/30/2013 11:36:57 PM  11/29/2013 11:18:34 PM  (null)
13  11/30/2013 11:36:57 PM  12/1/2013 6:52:19 PM    11/30/2013 7:37:45 PM   19.2561

Full query

```
DECLARE startDate VARCHAR (50);
  DECLARE endDate   VARCHAR (50);
  DECLARE mylogID   INT;
  DECLARE myItemId varchar (50);
  DECLARE myItemId2 varchar (50);
  DECLARE xHours varchar (50);

  SET startDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000);
  SET endDate   = FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000);
  SET mylogID   = (SELECT logID FROM logs WHERE details LIKE 'FCT%' LIMIT 1);
  SET myItemID = (SELECT i.itemId FROM items i  WHERE i.name LIKE '%KW PRE%');
  SET myItemID2 = (SELECT i.itemId FROM items i  WHERE  i.name LIKE '%KW STA%');

  SET @sql = NULL;
  SET @sql = CONCAT(
 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable3 AS (SELECT
    @row := @row + 1 AS rownum,
    a.logId,
    L1.recordId,
    L2.recordId AS next_recordId,
    L1.completed,
    L2.completed AS next_completed,
    L3.completed AS first_completed,
    L1.activityId AS activityJoin,
    L2.activityId AS next_activityId,
    IF(L1.activityId = L2.activityId, 1, NULL) AS isError,
     CASE
        when a.name LIKE ''%Enable%'' THEN time_to_sec(timediff(L2.completed, L1.completed)) / 3600
        ELSE NULL
        END AS coolingHours,
     TO_SECONDS(L2.completed) - TO_SECONDS(L1.completed) AS timeInSeconds,
    ((SUBSTR(l.details, INSTR(l.details, '':'') + 1))) AS charge,
    time_to_sec(timediff(''', endDate, ''', ''', startDate, ''')) / 3600 AS totalTimeRange,
    CONVERT_TZ(''', startDate, ''', ''UTC'', ''US/Pacific'') AS startingDate, 
    CONVERT_TZ(''', endDate, ''', ''UTC'', ''US/Pacific'') AS endingDate,
    ((L1.item', myItemID, ' - L1.item', myItemID2, ') * 
        (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(L2.completed, L1.completed)))) / 3600 AS kwDifference,
    ((L1.item', myItemID, ' - L1.item', myItemID2, ') * (SUBSTR(l.details, INSTR(l.details, '':'') + 1))) AS cost,
    ((((L1.item', myItemID, ' - L1.item', myItemID2, ') * (SUBSTR(l.details, INSTR(l.details,'':'') + 1)))
    * (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(L2.completed, L1.completed)) / 3600))) AS costT,
    DATABASE() AS databaseName, i.itemId ,l.details
FROM
    (SELECT @row:=0)R,
    (SELECT T1.completed
         , (SELECT MIN(T2.completed) 
            FROM log',mylogID, ' T2
            WHERE T2.completed > T1.completed) AS next_completed
         , (SELECT MAX(T2.completed) 
            FROM log',mylogID, ' T2
            WHERE T2.completed < T1.completed) AS frst_completed
    FROM log',mylogID, ' T1
    ORDER BY T1.completed
     )TimeOrder
        LEFT JOIN log', mylogID, ' L1 ON (L1.completed = TimeOrder.completed)
        LEFT JOIN log', mylogID, ' L2 ON (L2.completed = TimeOrder.next_completed)
        LEFT JOIN log', mylogID, ' L3 ON (L3.completed = TimeOrder.frst_completed)
        LEFT JOIN activities a ON L1.activityId = a.activityId
        LEFT JOIN logs l ON a.logId = l.logId
        inner join items i ON l.logId = i.logId AND i.name LIKE ''%KW PRE%'' 
    )order by L1.completed');  

 SET @sqlTemp = NULL;
  SET @sqlTemp = CONCAT(
  'SELECT 
    IF (coolingHours is null AND rowNum = min(rowNum) THEN ''',startDate,''':= first_completed END IF, 
    rowNum,l.logId,l.completed,l.next_completed,l.first_completed,
    isError,charge,totalTimeRange,startingDate,endingDate,coolingHours,
    databaseName,i.name,l.itemId, kwDifference, cost, costT,l.details,timeInSeconds
  FROM tempTable3 l
   inner join items i ON l.logId = i.logId AND i.name LIKE ''%KW PRE%'' 
   WHERE l.itemId = ''',myItemId,'''
        AND completed BETWEEN ''', startDate, ''' AND ''', endDate, '''
 '); 

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

PREPARE stmtTemp FROM @sqlTemp;
 EXECUTE stmtTemp;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtTemp;


 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable3
```

Comment: `''',startDate,'''` try with `',startDate,'`

Comment: That made no difference:  here is ; 1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN 2013-11-26 06:00:00:= first_completed END IF, 
    rowNum,l.logId,l.comple' at line 2

Comment: can you place your code in sqlfiddle.com

Comment: an inline IF is in this format `IF (condition,truevalue,falsevalue)` there's no THEN or END IF

Comment: @TinTran . . . You should add that as an answer, so it can be upvoted and accepted.

Comment: @tin tran I changed it to this SELECT 
    IF ((coolingHours is null AND rowNum = min(rowNum),(''',startDate,''':= first_completed),''',startDate,'''), 
    rowNum,l.logId,l.completed,l.next_completed,l.first_completed, ...  but still get this error 2 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= first_completed),'2013-11-26 06:00:00'), 
    rowNum,l.logId,l.completed,l.n' at line 2

Comment: try `IF (coolingHours is NULL AND rowNum = min(rowNum),first_completed,",startDate,"),`

Comment: @GordonLinoff, because the question is huge, i am not sure if what i say can be accepted until it actually fixes the problem :)

Comment: @jcho360 I tired to get this into sqlFiddle but it is pretty complex to change up

Comment: And what is `rownum = min(rownum)`?  I cannot think of a situation where this would actually be useful.  I suspect your query has many problems.

Comment: and the dividing varchar by 1000, that is some weird coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an inline IF is in this format `IF (condition,truevalue,falsevalue)` there's no `THEN` or `END IF`

try `IF (coolingHours is NULL AND rowNum = min(rowNum),first_completed,",startDate,"),`

Comment: That is MUCH closer to what I am looking for but what I am needing it to do is actually assign the value of first_completed to startDate if true. The way I have it written now it returns the IF as part of the select statement which when looking at it makes sense but that is not actually what I want. So how do I need to change the stored procedure up to make this IF set startDate to be or equal first_complete and use that in the where statement.

Comment: try `SELECT startDate:=IF(coolingHours is NULL AND rowNum = min(rowNum),first_completed,",startDate,"),` ... if that doesn't work you can always add the IF(...) again in the `WHERE` when you're comparing.

Comment: the above is still going to just return the startDate in the select statement - how would I put this in the where clause and make sure that it assigns the correct value to startDate BEFORE it hits the 'completed between startDate and endDate part of the code.

Comment: what I meant was you can try instead of `AND completed BETWEEN ''', startDate, ''' AND ''', endDate, '''` replace the `startDate` with your `IF(...)`

Comment: or you can run another SELECT before hand and assign the value there.

Comment: I changed it to this...SET @sqlTemp = CONCAT(
  'SELECT 
    rowNum,l.logId,l.completed,l.next_completed,l.first_completed,
 isError,charge,totalTimeRange,startingDate,endingDate,coolingHours,
    databaseName,i.name,l.itemId, kwDifference, cost, costT,l.details,timeInSeconds
  FROM tempTable3 l
   inner join items i ON l.logId = i.logId AND i.name LIKE ''%KW PRE%'' 
   WHERE l.itemId = ''',myItemId,''' AND completed BETWEEN IF(coolingHours is NULL AND rowNum = in(rowNum),first_completed,''',startDate,''') AND ''', endDate, '''
 ') which gives me an error of 1 Invalid use of group function

Comment: I thought about adding it as a select before hand but I need it to execute against the sqlTemp return data set as opposed to the sql as that will return all data and will always start with row 1

Comment: I am having problem understanding your stored-procedure.

Comment: sql creates a temporary table (tempTable3) - this is was done to ensure the correct order of rows (the end user is able to manipulate the orders) - the second one is what I need to focus on - if the tempTable has 25 rows of date I might actually only be selecting rows 10 - 20 - IF row ten, column coolingHours is NULL AND rowNum is min(rowNum) (which would indicate the first row of returned set) then I need to assign the value in first_completed to the variable startDate this would effectively cause the row 9 to also be included in the return set.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44076/discussion-between-portlight-and-tin-tran)